# Syntax error at or near "IF" PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, if-statement

I am trying to use subselect in my code but it gives me an error. I have found a lot of solution but it still does not work:

Here is my code:

```
BEGIN;
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE Z = 'aaaaa') = 0

    THEN
    INSERT INTO table2 (X, Y) VALUES ("abc", 7)

END IF;
END;
```

and error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 2: IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE Path = 'aaaaa') = 0
        ^


********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "IF"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 8
```

Could you help me?

Comment: For anybody else reading this later, note that the poster has omitted the surrounding `DO` block or function definition. You cannot run anonymous PL/PgSQL blocks in PostgreSQL, they must be surrounded by a `DO` or `CREATE [OR REPLACE] FUNCTION` with a `LANGUAGE` clause.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Drop the semicolon after "BEGIN"? That's if this is the body of a plpgsql function.

If this is a psql script, the `IF` statement needs to be given to plpgsql to execute, so it needs putting in a `DO $$ ... $$` construct.

Or, of course, you could refactor like so:

```
INSERT INTO table2(x,y)
    SELECT 'abc', 7
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE z = 'aaaaa')
```

Comment: Oh, it looks like a solution..but I do not understand how it works...I want to check if record exists, if yes -do nothing, if no insert record - how it works your INSERT code ?

Comment: INSERT does not have to have a fixed set of values, it can take as input any SELECT. So the SELECT part you can run on its own, and it produces `('abc', 7)` iff the row does not exist. This result can then be given to the INSERT.

Comment: Hmmmm, so let's assume I have got: INSERT INTO Table (X, Y) Values (A, B) but only in case when value B does not exist in Y column. How will be look all code?

Comment: I have got one question more...how can I use it in MySQL ?

Comment: @javaGirl sorry, I don't know about mysql.